# Mecanics in videogames : spring and gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble calculating the vertical movement of my object.
Say I have an object held to the ceiling by a spring and the original speed and position may vary.

So I tried something like this :

```
Vector3 springSpeed = attachPoint - position;
Vector3 speed = initialSpeed + new Vector3(springSpeed.x, springSpeed.y - 9.81, springSpeed.z);

// and prepare for next frame
initialSpeed = speed;
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.
How can I have a normal behavior ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law

Comment: There's no general simple case in here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't compute everything yourself.

You can use the physic engine of Unity to do all this work for you, Create an object, add a rigidbody component so it simulate physics, then create an other object on the "ceiling" which will serve as an anchor and add a Spring component on your first object and set the connected body to the second.

See more informations here :

- [RigidBody](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)
- [Spring](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html)